# How to integrate photoshop subscripts into the main script?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript

I have no programming knowledge of JavaScript and following script created by [ActionToJavascript](https://github.com/Hennamann/CEP-Toolkit/blob/master/JSX%20Utility%20Scripts/ActionToJavascript.jsx):
[Main Script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HqFwHqvUfsf3TKYpXhw6ApK-ffZ5LMJ6/view?usp=sharing)
(i can't put here because my script is very long)
**Now i want to put following subscripts to above script.**

line 82: [color_range_2_rectangular_selectionn.jsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dxjaJ3pZkm3BZ6hXkE8AwzzWQkXFtMJo/view?usp=sharing)
line 391: [spl2lay.jsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ro40x9PYyxjQDch-KtlS3sj2edGY-H6O/view?usp=sharing)
line 466: [remv_color_range_selection.jsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h1EP-oW92pH2X2xj2grmk98rO5EnP3mR/view?usp=sharing)
line 488: [Flip_All_Layers.jsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Osp4B7XrPrxAlUqJx78OUwZLcOUForGR/view?usp=sharing)

**please tell me a simple way to replace subscripts into my main script.

Note that i have no programming knowledge of JavaScript and only need a completed sample script to learn this**

Comment: This is, forgive me, asking a *lot* from "designers". Script editing is more of a programming skill than design skill. This *might* fit a bit more on http://stackoverflow.com - I don't know. In general, terms one can often copy/paste scripts into each other to combine processes. However, the skill and knowledge come in where *troubleshooting* is concerned. One needs to know what functions do and alleviate any conflicts within the combined script. There is often no  easy or simple way to combine several javascripts. The more complex the scripts are, the more difficult the challenge becomes.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a little light on details, and I can't access the links so it's hard to tell if this is helpful, but you can have the main script (created by ActionToJavascript) call your sub-scripts by adding the following code and updating the path. You'd need to update the function name as well:

```
// Scripts
  function step38(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var estr = '//@include "~/[path-to-script]/[script].jsx";\r\n';
    eval(estr);
  };
```